# Python and Yolov5, using a buffer to stabilize FPS create strange pattern

Tags: python, camera, real-time, yolo

I am  not understanding something, maybe someone can shine some light on it.

I am doing image recognition in Python with torch (YOLOv5  2023-4-19 Python-3.9.13 torch-2.0.0+cu117 CUDA:0 (NVIDIA RTX A2000 8GB Laptop GPU, 8192MiB) on real time camera stream.

I need to have a stable frequency. So I implemented something like this:

[image: Here is a graph representing my process]

Where my buffer allow me to set the frequency on my process.
Lets say for example I do the loop in 120 milliseconds +- 10 milliseconds so I set my buffer to wait until 200 milliseconds.

As an example (I tried several variation) I make my buffer like, this:

```py
import timeit

frame_delay = 0.1
main_time_buffer = timeit.default_timer()


[LOOP]
    current = timeit.default_timer()
    if current - main_time_buffer < frame_delay:
        time.sleep(frame_delay-(current - main_time_buffer))
    main_time_buffer = timeit.default_timer()
```

Works, but then something strange happens with my image recognition task.

Here is the timing without a buffer:
[image: Timing without buffer]

And here is the behavior with a buffer:
[image: behavior with buffer]

[image: behavior with buffer]

The buffer makes the classification slower, but also behaving in a very random way.
(Note: the buffer do not match the classification because of the camera too)

I am very confused by this behavior...
Why is the buffer impacting the time for the classification?

Is there a frequency inside of the GPU? Because I suppose I am pretty slow to hit that.
Am I hitting some resonant state of the GPU?

Any suggestion would be appreciated, because I really don't get it here.

I need to process image from a camera at a precise frequency, so I implemented a time buffer to get a stable frequency du to variation in my my processing time depending of the number of object detected.